# Integrating WebSocket Streaming with Express Middleware for OpenAI API Responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, openai-api

I am working on an Express.js application where I need to integrate OpenAI's streaming API responses to be sent in real-time to a front-end via WebSockets. I've set up WebSocket server and client communication, but I'm facing challenges in streaming the data from an OpenAI API response through WebSockets during an HTTP request.

Here is the situation:

- I have a middleware in server.js that should attach a map of user
  sockets to each request, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
- In my controller, during an API request, I want to access the user's
  WebSocket and stream data to it as it comes in from OpenAI's API.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**server.js;**

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const app = require("./app");

....

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App runnig on port ${port}...`);
});

const userSockets = new Map();

app.use((req, res, next) => { //Doesn't work
  req.userSockets = userSockets;
  next();
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  console.log("WebSocket connection established");

  const userId = "11111111111";
  userSockets.set(userId, ws);

  ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
    console.log("Received via WebSocket:", message.toString());
    if (message.toString() === "ping") {
      ws.send("pong");
    }
  });

  ws.on("close", function () {
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
  });
});

....
```

**app.js;**

```
...

const appRouter = require("./routes/appRoutes");

app.use("/app", appRouter);

....

module.exports = app;
```

**appRoutes.js;**

```
router.get("/testStream", appController.testStream, ...);
```

**appController.js;**

```
exports.testStream = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

  const ws = req.userSockets.get("11111111111");          

  if (!ws) {
    return next(new AppError("WebSocket connection not found", 404));
  }

  const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: model,
    messages: messages,
    stream: true,
  });

  const collected_stream = [];

  for await (const part of stream) {
    if (
      part.choices &&
      part.choices[0] &&
      part.choices[0].delta &&
      "content" in part.choices[0].delta
    ) {
      ws.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "content",
          data: part.choices[0].delta.content,
        })
      );
      collected_stream.push(part.choices[0].delta.content);
      console.log(part.choices[0].delta.content);
    }
  }

  console.log(collected_stream.join(""));

  req.data = {
      historyId: "",
      content: collected_stream.join(""),
    };

  next();
});
```

I am expecting the middleware to attach userSockets to req, but req.userSockets appears to be undefined within my route controller.

1. How can I correctly pass the userSockets map to the middleware so it's available in the request object within my route controllers?
2. Once I have access to the correct WebSocket in my controller, is there a best practice for sending OpenAI API stream data through it?

I have read the relevant Express and WebSocket documentation but have not found a solution that fits this particular case. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, I created a global map structure to store WebSocket connections in a file named connection.js, and included this file in my server.js

**connection.js**

```
const clients = new Map();
module.exports = clients;
```

Next, I used this structure in my server.js file to match the user ID from the cookies with the WebSocket:

```
....
const clients = require("./utils/connection");
const cookie = require("cookie");
const { verifyJwt } = require("./utils/verifyJwt");
....

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws, req) {

  const cookies = req.headers.cookie ? cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie) : {};
  const id = verifyJwt(cookies["access"]);
  if (!id) {
    ws.close();
    return;
  }

  clients.set(id.toString(), ws);


  console.log("WebSocket connection established for user", id);
  console.log("Active client number:", clients.size);

  ws.on("close", function () {
    clients.delete(id);
    console.log("Active client number:", clients.size);
  });
});
```

Finally, in my appController.js file, I utilized these connections to stream data from the OpenAI API to the client over WebSockets:

appController.js:

```
...
const clients = require("../utils/connection");
const WebSocket = require("ws"); 
...

exports.testStream = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

  const clientWs = clients.get(req.user._id.toString());

  ...

  // Send data from the stream over WebSocket
  for await (const part of stream) {
    if (part.choices && part.choices[0] && part.choices[0].delta && "content" in part.choices[0].delta) {
      if (clientWs && clientWs.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        clientWs.send(part.choices[0].delta.content);
      }
      collected_stream.push(part.choices[0].delta.content);
    }
  }

  ...

  next();
});
```

This approach allowed me to successfully stream the OpenAI API responses via WebSockets.  I hope this solution can help others encountering similar issues.